# angularjs - constructor injection with arguments

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm trying to instantiate an object using the angular.factory recipe. The factory code is something like this

```
monevAppServices.factory('MonEvChartService', ['element','chartConfig',function monEvChartFactory(element,chartConfig) {

    return MonEvChart;
}
```

where element and chartconfig are arguments expected by the MonEvChart, something like

```
new MonEvChart(element,chartConfig);
```

However when I try to use this service in my controller (after injecting it)

```
angular.module('monevApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('NewDashboard',
        ['$rootScope','$scope','subscribedMonitor','MonEvChartService','$log',
            function($rootScope,$scope,subscribedMonitor,MonEvChartService,$log) {

        ...

    $scope.monevchart  = new MonEvChartService($scope.element,$scope.chartConfig);    
...
```

It throws an error like

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: elementProvider - element  - MonEvChartService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=elementProvider%20%3C-%20element%20%3C-%20MonEvChartService
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
```

Any help guidance would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't instantiate services like that.  AngularJS creates those objects for you similar to how Spring creates beans in Java.  So you can't parameterize it like that either.  If you wanted to create something like that you'd need to create a factory method you do the following:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xnGJxq

But what you are trying to do is build a directive for a charting component.  A service won't work for you because it doesn't do anything with the UI.  So you want to learn about directives and how to build those:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: thanks for your response. The link for plnkr is not working. Can you please repost. If you look at the angularjs developer documentation - http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers , the example shows how to provide arguments for constructor injection. However it does not show how to invoke the service - and where i'm blocked. Just like spring where you can provide the constructor arguments as a configuration  there must be a way to to instantiate any object with custom arguments in angular too. What I'm understanding from your response severly restricts the object creation in angular.

Comment: Ok the plunker is updated.  It will inject, but only what's in the container (ie angular app).  That won't be elements from the dom tree.  And you don't instantiate objects in the angular app using new either.  You just declare a dependency in the function definition, and angularjs will give you a reference to it.  If you want to manipulate the dom your want a directive not a service.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after spending some time and re-reading the developer documentation , this is the working solution i came up with. Would really like to hear if someone has an opinion on it

```
//removed the constructor arguments
monevAppServices.factory('MonEvChart', [function monEvChartFactory() {
        return MonEvChart;
}]);

...

//instantiating the object in the controller and passing in the arguments
monevchart   = new MonEvChart(element,config);
                monevchart.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason why we cannot add parameters when creating services in angularJs has something to do with dependency injection. Most, if not all, IoC containers requires a parameterless constructor. I think this is true for angularJs injector as well.